# Different methods of computing standard deviation not agreeing

Tags: standard-deviation

I have been assigned the following problem:
Given numbers  -25, 2, 3, 8, 10, 14, 18, 21, 32

> You are told the mean of the numbers is 9.222 and the mean of their
> square is 309.666. What is the sample standard deviation?

The answer is given as
$\sqrt{9/8 * (309.666-9.222^2)} =15.896$

This is a new way of calculating standard deviation to me.
So I tried the old way I know with a spreadsheet in yellow.
I get the answer as 44.92

What am I missing?

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide $2021.556$ by $9-1=8$ before taking the square root.

Comment: n- 9, divide by n-1 if it is a sample